# Twilio client not receiving incoming event

Tags: twilio, twilio-javascript

I am trying to build a phone component that can handle twilio calls and I got outgoing working but when I try to receive phone calls no events are fired and my console shows no answer from the client, my token is given identity test, this is the twiml returned

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial answerOnBridge="true" callerId="(my twilio phone number)">
      <Client>
        <Identity>
          test
        </Identity>
      </Client>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

The browser has a console.log added to the device.on("incoming") event but it does not fire, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `incomingAllow = true` set in your voice grant in your access token?

Comment: Yes I did set it

Comment: Is this using Twilio Voice JS version 1 or 2? Can you share exactly what you are doing to try to connect the call (for example, what is triggering the webhook that is getting the above TwiML in response?). Can you share your JavaScript for receiving the call in the browser?

Comment: @philnash, please following question I am facing the same issue, I ask question with detailed descriptions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72729191/twilio-voice-sdk-does-not-listen-incoming-call-listener-when-i-call-on-my-twilio